# How to edit the legend of a scatter plot?

Tags: r, legend, scatter3d

I made a plot with legend. By this code:

```
scatter3d(x = red, y = green, z = blue, groups = C1class$V1, surface. col = 1:21,
      grid = FALSE, surface = FALSE)
legend3d("right", legend = levels(C1class$V1),
   col = rainbow(21), pch = 16, inset = -0.25, xpd = TRUE)
```

But my graph looks like this:

[image]

How can I edit it to look better?
Can you help me with some function to fix it?
Thanks for you help.

Comment: What do you want it to look like? Can you supply some sample data to replicate your plot?

Comment: I want to make visible legend for plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not provide your data, so I cannot test your problem exactly, 
but I think that the example below will help you solve your problem.

I think that your problem stems from including the parameter `inset = -0.25`. 
That is shifting the legend out of the display area. Looking at your picture,
I think that the reason that you did that is because otherwise the 
legend covers over part of the scatterplot. A different way to fix this is to adjust the drawing area using `windowRect` to allow more space.

A plot like yours with the legend chopped off.

```
scatter3d(x = iris[,1], y = iris[,2], z = iris[,3], groups = iris[,5], 
    surface.col = rainbow(3), grid = FALSE, surface = FALSE)
legend3d("right", legend = levels(iris[,5]),
   col = rainbow(3), inset = -0.25, pch = 16, xpd = TRUE)
```

[image: Cropped legend]

---

A second plot without the indent.  Now the legend overlaps the plot.

```
scatter3d(x = iris[,1], y = iris[,2], z = iris[,3], groups = iris[,5], 
    surface.col = rainbow(3), grid = FALSE, surface = FALSE)
legend3d("right", legend = levels(iris[,5]),
   col = rainbow(3), pch = 16, xpd = TRUE)
```

[image: Legend overlaps plot]

---

Finally, the window size is adjusted to allow more room for the legend.

```
par3d(windowRect = c(100, 100, 600, 350))
scatter3d(x = iris[,1], y = iris[,2], z = iris[,3], groups = iris[,5], 
    surface.col = rainbow(3), grid = FALSE, surface = FALSE)
legend3d("right", legend = levels(iris[,5]),
   col = rainbow(3), pch = 16, xpd = TRUE)
```

[image: Desired result]

You may need to adjust the `windowRec` differently for your data, but this setting will be a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you very much. It help me a lot.